# How to get InputStream from request in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, chunked

Ithink this used to be possible in Play 1.x, but I can't find how to do it in Play 2.x

I know that Play is asynchronous and uses `Iteratee`s. However, there is generally much better support for `InputStream`s.

(In this case, I will be using a streaming JSON parser like Jackson to process the request body.)

How can I get an `InputStream` from a chunked request body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following code:

```
// I think all of the parens and braces line up -- copied/pasted from code
val pos = new PipedOutputStream()
val pis = new PipedInputStream(pos)
val result = Promise[Either[Errors, String]]()

def outputStreamBodyParser = {
  BodyParser("outputStream") {
    requestHeader =>
      val length = requestHeader.headers(HeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH).toLong

      Future {
        result.completeWith(saveFile(pis, length)) // save returns Future[Either[Errors, String]]
      }

      Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], OutputStream](pos) {
        (os, data) =>
          os.write(data)
          os
      }.map {
        os =>
          os.close()
          Right(os)
      }
  }
}

Action.async(parse.when(
  requestHeaders => {
    val maybeContentLength = requestHeaders.headers.get(HeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH)
    maybeContentLength.isDefined && allCatch.opt(maybeContentLength.get.toLong).isDefined
  },
  outputStreamBodyParser,
  requestHeaders => Future.successful(BadRequest("Missing content-length header")))) {
    request =>
    result.future.map {
      case Right(fileRef) => Ok(fileRef)
      case Left(errors) => BadRequest(errors)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Play 2 is meant to be fully asynchronous, so this isn't easily possible or desirable. The problem with `InputStream` is there is no push back, there is no way for the reader of the `InputStream` to communicate to the input that it wants more data without blocking on `read`. Technically it is possible to write an `Iteratee` that could read data and put it into an `InputStream`, and would wait for a call to `read` on the `InputStream` before asking the `Enumerator` for more data, but it would be dangerous. You would have to make sure that the `InputStream` was closed properly, or the `Enumerator` would sit waiting forever (or until it times out) and the call to `read` must be made from a thread that is not running on the same `ExecutionContext` as the `Enumerator` and `Iteratee` or the application could deadlock.